# Compute a students grade based on weight of assignments

Tags: python, beginner

Hoping to get feedback on how this program could be written in the most pythonic way. Also welcome any criticisms of styling as I know this is not in accordance with pep-8

```
from collections import namedtuple
a = namedtuple('assignment', 'weight scores')
def average(scores:list):
    '''average a list of scores'''
    return sum(scores)/len(scores)
def get_grade(grades:list):
    '''compute final grade based on scores and their weights'''
    result = 0
    for a in grades:
        result += average(a.scores) * a.weight
    return result 
def main():
   grades = [a(.30, [18/45, 11/55]),
             a(.20, [3/10, 7.5/10, 10/10]),
             a(.10, [9/10, 9/10, 10/10, 10/10, 8/10,
                6/10, 10/10, 10/10]),
             a(.40, [29/65]), 
             a(.01, [1/1])]
   print(get_grade(grades))
main()
```

Comment: Just posting a script without any description or what you hope to achieve from posting it is only going to attract downvotes and leave your question unanswered.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Code Review!  Please review [How do I ask a good Question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Specifically, it is best to explain what the code does.  And it is also code to discuss a bit about what your are hoping for from a review.

Comment: Thanks sorry new to the community and  will be more descriptive next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import namedtuple
```

You should put blank lines after imports, and between function/class definitions.

---

```
a = namedtuple('assignment', 'weight scores')
```

Using a `namedtuple` for a simple data class like this is a good idea, but it should still be named as a class; `Assignment`.

---

```
def average(scores:list):
    '''average a list of scores'''
    return sum(scores)/2
```

This function has an obvious bug; what about lists of scores with lengths other than two? Also you type the parameter but not the return value, and should again have some more whitespace; I'd write:

```
def average(scores: list) -> float:
    """Average a list of scores."""
    return sum(scores) / len(scores)
```

See [PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for docstring conventions.

---

```
def get_grade(grades:list):
    '''compute final grade based on scores and their weights'''
    result = 0
    for a in grades:
        result += average(a.scores) * a.weight
    return result
```

I think you could simplify this with a bit more OOP. If we subclass the named tuple we can add a read only calculated attribute to it:

```
class Assignment(namedtuple('Assignment', 'weight scores')):

    @property
    def result(self) -> float:
        return average(self.scores) * self.weight
```

Then your function becomes:

```
def get_grade(assignments: list) -> float:
    """Compute final grade based on scores and their weights."""
    return sum(a.result for a in assignments)
```

Note the revised parameter name, which better describes the input.

---

```
def main():
   grades = [a(.30, [18/45, 11/55]),
             a(.20, [3/10, 7.5/10, 10/10]),
             a(.10, [9/10, 9/10, 10/10, 10/10, 8/10,
                6/10, 10/10, 10/10]),
             a(.40, [29/65]), 
             a(.01, [1/1])]
   print(get_grade(grades))
main()
```

To keep things looking consistent without introducing a lot of indentation, I usually split lists with long elements across multiple lines as follows:

```
assignments = [
    Assignment(.30, [18/45, 11/55]),
    ...
    Assignment(
        .10,
        [9/10, 9/10, 10/10, 10/10, 8/10, 6/10, 10/10, 10/10]
    ),
    ...
]
```

Note splitting between, rather than within, the two parameters.

Also you should guard the invocation of the entry point as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

This means you can import this functionality more easily for testing and reuse.

Comment: Note that in Python 2.x, your `average` function has a small bug. If `sum(scores)` is an integer, it will do integer division (because `len(scores)` is also an integer), instead of float division. Just wrap either the `sum` or the `len` in a `float` call to avoid it.

Comment: @Graipher you're correct, but given the integer divisions in the rest of the OP's code I assumed they'd have been bitten by that already if they were using 2.x!